# Android Studio: Deleting Item from ChildRecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm currently building a schedule app where users can input information, and the app will organize the information in a list with each day of the week as the header with each corresponding activity under the day. I'm using a parent child recyclerview to do this (i.e. each day of the week is a part of the parent recyclerview and each activity in the schedule is part of the child recyclerview). Right now I'm trying to add a swipe to delete information in the child recyclerview. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this using the parent child recyclerview configuration, where I have two different adapters for each recyclerview?

Code for Parent RecyclerView:

```
public class MainRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<DayHeader> weekList;
private Context mContext;

public MainRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<DayHeader> weekList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.weekList = weekList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayofweekheader,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DayHeader section = weekList.get(position);
    String nameofday = section.getDayName();
    ArrayList<medinfo> meditems = section.getmMedItems();
    holder.weekdayname.setText(nameofday);

    MedicationAdapter childrecyclerAdapter = new MedicationAdapter(mContext,meditems);
    holder.childrecyclerview.setAdapter(childrecyclerAdapter);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return weekList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView weekdayname;
    RecyclerView childrecyclerview;

      public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        weekdayname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weekdayheader);
        childrecyclerview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.childrecyclerview);
    }
}
```

}

Code for Child RecyclerView:

```
public class MedicationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MedicationAdapter.MedicationViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<medinfo> mMedList;
private Context mContext;


public static class MedicationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mMedname;
    public TextView mTime;
    public TextView mNumbPills;
    public ImageView popup;


    public MedicationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mMedname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.medname);
        mTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        mNumbPills = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberofpills);
        popup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menumore);

    }
}

public MedicationAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<medinfo> medList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mMedList = medList;


}

@NonNull
@Override
public MedicationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,parent,false);
    MedicationViewHolder mvh = new MedicationViewHolder(v);
    return mvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MedicationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    medinfo currentItem = mMedList.get(position);
    String medName = "Medication: " + currentItem.getmMedName();
    holder.mMedname.setText(medName);
    String medTime = "Time: " + currentItem.getmTime();
    holder.mTime.setText(medTime);
    String numbPills = "# of Pills: " + currentItem.getmNumbPills();
    holder.mNumbPills.setText(numbPills);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMedList.size();
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mMedList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mMedList.size());
}
```

}

I also have this SwipeItem class:

```
public class SwipeItem extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

MedicationAdapter mMedAdapter;

SwipeItem(MedicationAdapter mMedAdapter){
    super(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
    this.mMedAdapter = mMedAdapter;
}
@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    int position = viewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
    this.mMedAdapter.removeItem(position);

}
```

}

So how can I implement the SwipeItem in my adapter codes to delete each child item?

Comment: I'm not sure what's do want exactly.
can you be more specific.
and share the code

Comment: I added some code, hopefully this clarifies! Thanks!